# JW player videos not playing in mobile

Tags: video, jwplayer

Recently, the mobile videos on a site I'm working on stopped working.

Through some tests, it seems like something is covering the player up. Because if I do a click event and target my video block, it doesn't do anything when I click it.

The really weird thing is that if I make a click event for html, html *, body or body *, still nothing happens when clicking on the player. If i click on items above or below the player, those events will fire though so I know the events are setup correctly.

If something is covering the player up, I have no idea what it could be. I tried increasing the z-index of the video block by a lot and still nothing. The thumbnail list below the video will play a video so it doesn't appear that the player itself is having an issue.

Here's a link to a page with a video player:
http://rossrichardson.com/commercials/bentley

EDIT: Just checked in iOS7 and the videos play fine. Seems to be an iOS8 issue.

Comment: This is JW 5.7. I would at the very least update to 5.10. However, keep in mind that when JW5 was released, iOS8 wasn't even on the horizon yet, as JW5 was released over 3 years ago at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the last v. 6.10 of JwPlayer. This is the guide about migration: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1404037-migrating-from-jw5-to-jw6